# how to run React + express + node on nginx ec2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

Everything works fine on local machine, Please let me if my server setup is correct

Project Structure

```
/client/--React frontend app
/client/package.json
/index.js
/package.json -- express server
```

In My /index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}

app.listen(process.env.B_PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log(`Express server Up and Running - Port : ${process.env.B_PORT}`);
});
```

In My /client/package.json

```
{
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
}
```

I am getting 405 not allow for post request, but when i do http://myec2ip:5000 i can json response from express.

What config am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open port 5000 in security group setting of ec2 and allow anyone to access it using 0.0.0.0 for incoming connections.